# Converting a .txt file with 1 million digits of "e" into a vector in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a text file with 1 million decimal digits of "e" number with 80 digits on each line excluding the first and the last line which have 76 and 4 digits and the file has 12501 lines. I want to convert it into a vector in matlab with each digit on each row. I tried `num2str` function, but the problem is that it gets converted like for example `'7.1828e79'` (13 characters). What can I do?

P.S.1: The first two lines of the text file (76 and 80 digits) are:

7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535 47594571382178525166427427466391932003059921817413596629043572900334295260595630

P.S.2: I used "dlmread" and got a 12501x1 vector, with the first and second row of 7.18281828459045e+75 and 4.75945713821785e+79 and the problem is that when I use num2str for example for the first row value, I get: '7.182818284590453e+75' as a string and not the whole 76 digits. My aim was to do something like this:

```
e1=dlmread('e.txt');
es1=num2str(e1);
for i=1:12501
    for j=1:length(es1(1,:))
        a1((i-1)*length(es1(1,:))+j)=es1(i,j);
    end
end
e_digits=a1.';
```

but I get a string like this:
a1='7.182818284590453e+754.759457138217852e+797.381323286279435e+799.244761460668082e+796.133138458300076e+791.416928368190255e+79 5...'
with 262521 characters instead of 1 million digits.

P.S.3: I think the problem might be solved if I can manipulate the text file in a way that I have one digit on each line and simply use dlmread.

Comment: Are you able to read the file into (a) matlab (variable)? Can you give a (simplified) example of what you are trying to obtain. Please try to be as concrete as possible without giving irrelevant information, see [ask].

Comment: Do you want to truncate `2.` from `2.718281...`?  If not, what would you want for the decimal point `.`? `NaN`?

Comment: Please, add the first two lines of the txt file and the code you tried to the question

Comment: I edited the question and added the required information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this is not hard, there are many ways to do it.

So first you want to load in your file as a Char Array using something simple like (you want a Char Array so that you can easily manipulate it to  forget about the lines breaks) :

```
 C = fileread('yourfile.txt'); %loads file as Char Array
 D = C(~isspace(C));     %Removes SPACES which are line-breaks
```

Next, you want to actually append a SPACE between each char (this is because you want to use the num2str transform - and matlab needs to see the space), you can do this using a RESHAPE, a STRTRIM or simply a REGEX:

```
 E = strtrim(regexprep(D, '.{1}', '$0 ')); %Add a SPACE after each Numeric Digit
```

Now you can transform it using str2num into a Vector:

```
 str2num(E)'; %Converts the Char Array back to Vector
```

which will give you a single digit each row.

Using your example, I get a vector of 156 x 1, with 1 digit each row as you required.

Comment: @AliEftekhariMilani could you accept the answer then :D ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get a digit per row like this

```
fid = fopen('e.txt','r');
c = textscan(fid,'%s');
c=cat(1,c{:});
c = cellfun(@(x) str2num(reshape(x,[],1)),c,'un',0);
c=cat(1,c{:});
```

And it is not the only possible way. 
Could you please tell what is the final task, how do you plan using the array of e digits?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm going to find the first 10-digit prime in the digits of e.